# Is there a way to define external checks on a GitHub PR?

Tags: github, pull-request, build-server

When I open a PR on GitHub, several builds are triggered on our external build server, but because of build queuing, they can run at different times.

In the interim, however, I can merge my PR after even one of the builds has successfully run.
I understand that the build server is probably using the Checks API, and that GitHub doesn't know about the check until the build server tells it that the build has started.  I think this is the source of the problem because GitHub is just saying, "All the checks I know about have passed."

Is there a way to configure GitHub to *expect* all of my builds before the build server starts them?